# jQuery click event on blank space

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to catch an event when a user clicks a blank space on the page with jQuery. For example, lets say you have the following:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <p>Here's some text!</p>
    <body>
</html>
```

I want to catch the event when the user clicks on **anything but** the p tag.

Is there a way to catch something like this?

Comment: I'm interested to know why you'd want that behavior?

Comment: I'm making a little web app that is similar to Taskpaper (for the Mac) and I want it to mimic the application's behavior. More of a proof of concept than anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works in chrome. Haven't tried other browsers. Works off the idea that stickmangumby had:

```
$('body').click( function (e) { 
    if ( e.target == this ) 
        alert('works'); 
});
```

Comment: Ahh, I forgot all about the target attribute. This fits in perfectly with what I got already. All of the other answers work as well, I just think that this one is the best for just handling the one event of handling clicks on the body(or in my case, the html tag level)

Comment: I just want to point out that this will not work for every point on the screen unless <body> is at least 100% of the window's width and height.

Comment: correct, which is why I switched it from the $('body') selector to the $('html') selector in my code to avoid manually changing the body's height and width.

Comment: not true if you have plain text right in the body tag

Comment: @KnIfER Since I answered this question over 10 years ago, I thought maybe something changed, but nope. It still works for me with just text in the body tag. https://jsfiddle.net/pokd9jbn/1/

If that isn't what you are referring to, you need to be more concise with your response.

Comment: I mean region of body that contains text nodes is no longer 'blank space'. In this jsfiddle, when you click on the text, the browser will also alert. But perhaps not a big problem in the asker's case.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to work:

```
$(function() {
    $('body').click(function() {
        alert('clicked the page');
        return false;
    });
    $('*:not(body)').click(function() {
        alert('clicked an item!');
        return false;
    });
});
```

One "problem" you'll have is that paragraphs are block elements by default, so clicking to the side of a sentence will produce an item click even if it looks like you haven't clicked on an item.

Answer (score 3):

I was searching for the solution of a similar problem - hide a custom tooltip when clicking the document, but not when clicking inside the tip. I did it like this (changed the selector to match the question):

```
$(document).bind('click', function(e) {
    if($(e.target).closest('p').length == 0) {
        //p is not clicked. do your stuff here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could observe the document for onclick, and then check the event.currentTarget in your event handling function.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm making a little web app that is
>   similar to Taskpaper (for the Mac) and
>   I want it to mimic the application's
>   behavior. More of a proof of concept
>   than anything else

In light of your comments, I wouldn't worry about the body specifically then. Instead wire up a div so that you can constrain the area you want to react to events. In the case where there's no other elements on the page, it's the same thing.

For what it's worth, on any web page, your users would hate you if clicking any whitespace anywhere does something - it would be a poor UI experience.

Comment: I think that depends greatly on what he's planning on doing when the event fires. It's pretty presumptuous to say what he's doing is bad if you don't know what he's doing.

Comment: Ah but I did ask as a comment why and I do have a good idea of what he's trying to do, which is why it's prefaced with "in light of your comments". I also think it's a bad idea to hook into the body-click event, even if it's a proof of concept.

Comment: "your users would hate you if clicking any whitespace anywhere does something - it would be a poor UI experience"

Actually, that's exactly what Taskpaper does. Anywhere you click in it's main window, you either are entering a new task or are editing something that is already on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (I think)

```
$('body').not('p').click(function(){});
```

Not sure how well that will work, though.

Comment: I believe that will just filter the selector and won't influence the click event bubbling.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but try this.

```
$('html').on('click',function(event){
    if(event['target'].tagName =='HTML'){
        //do stuff;
    }
})
```